# " I have a Dream"

Tags: meaning

What is the message/meaning of Martin Luther King Jr's famous Speech " I have a Dream"?

Comment: Look up the words *have* and *dream* and its meaning should become very clear. Good luck. If there are any words or expressions you do not understand, please check two or three online dictionaries they should help you understand more clearly.

Comment: If you are asking about the **phrase** "I have a dream" then [Oxford's definition 2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dream) (not 2.1) fits. If you are asking about the **entire speech** then the question is too broad.

Comment: Interpretation requests (criticism, discussion, analysis, and divining the author’s intent) are out of scope and may be removed. This applies to all English texts and utterances, song lyrics, poetry, and legal documents. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”, and the *[Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com/)*. If there is an unstated specific concern, such as a point of grammar or the meaning of an unfamiliar word, ask that question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will address only the title rather than the entire speech, but you need to consider the entire speech to establish the context for the title

In the speaker's context, it means *I have hope for a brighter future* or *I foresee a better world.*

This is consistent with *dream* as a noun as described in:

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dream)

"4 a :a strongly desired goal or purpose "

Comment: @KeaneCabezas  You are quite welcome.